# Using AMPScript in Custom Activity

Tags: ampscript, journeybuilder

Is it possible to use AMPScript in Custom Activity?

We have built a Custom Activity to send SMS using personlization, currently to personalize we are using the rest api to look up the data based on the mapping. Is it possible to directly use the AMPScript?

Thanks,
Thenna R

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want the [LookupRows](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookuprows.htm) option in AMPScript? It may be similar to what you're asking for.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, what i am looking for is, for e.g: 

This is my text in the content area of the custom activity

"Hi %%DE1.Name%%, This is your available balance points %%DE2.Point%%"

here look up is involved from 2 DE's.

Currently each time I am posting this content to a webhook and then use rest api to look up the data.

I am looking for instead of doing that directly get the data on the Journey execution.

Is there any way to it?